# RTP/RTSP library with MPEG-2 Audio/Video support

Tags: rtp

Can anybody suggest me any RTP/RTSP library other than OpenRTSP that has support for MPEG-2 ?  Basically I am developing my own RTP?RTSP client. I just wanted to have a look at logic for parsing RTP/RTSP payload header.
        Also I will highly appreciate if someone suggest me open source Dshow filters for receiving RTP?RTSP packets.

Regards,
Anand Shah

Comment: Https://net7mma.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg based direct show filter - called [ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow/) or VLC

If you are only interested in understanding the logic - try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) or [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/)'s RTP source. It is much neater.

Another source is [live555](http://live555.com/).